# How would I graph this implicit function in geogebra?

Tags: graphing-functions, implicit-differentiation, curves

I am trying to graph the below equation in geogebra.

\begin{equation} 
 x\cos { (xy) } = 4 -y
\end{equation}

I was able to get wolframalpha to graph it but I am unsure on how to in geogebra. I am assuming I should be using an implict type function. Anyone one know how I can do this?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xcos%28xy%29+%3D+4+-+y

Comment: Your question is probably better suited for the [GeoGebra User Forums](http://forum.geogebra.org/).

Comment: Yes. I realized this after I asked, I posted there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation in standard form ($f(x,y)=0$) and use the `ImplicitCurve` command:

[image: ImplicitCurve]